# C++ Iterate unordered_map and it's buckets (iterate all entries)

Tags: c++, iteration, hashtable, unordered-map, bucket

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate though an unordered_map and its buckets. All of the posts I find iterate but ignore the buckets. My understanding is the unordered_map can act as a Hash Table which allows collisions.

My Hash Table has collisions in it but when I try to iterate though the map, its not getting all the values.

```
for (int currGasIndex = 0; currGasIndex < gasValuesTable.size(); currGasIndex++)
        {
            for (unordered_map<EGasType, int>::iterator it = gasValuesTable.begin(currGasIndex); it != gasValuesTable.end(currGasIndex); ++it)
            {
                cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << endl;
            }

            std::cout << "=========================================================" << std::endl;
        }
```

My question is, how do I iterate the map to get all the values?

Comment: You iterate through it using iterators or a range based loop. If you have entries missing because of hash collisions (not duplicate keys, which are not allowed, see unordered_multimap for that) then it's possible your hash function and/or equality function are broken. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Ahh ok, the duplicate keys might be the issue. I'm adding to the unordered_map and some use the same key so I thought it would handle collisions of the same key by adding it to the list under that key like a Hash Table. I'll look into unordered_multimap.

Comment: The word "collision" doesn't mean what I suspect you think it means. "Collision" means that, for two keys `a` and `b`, `a != b` but `hash(a) == hash(b)`. You don't need to do anything special about that, `unordered_map` can handle it. This is entirely different from trying to insert two different values with the same key (that is, when `a == b`). `std::unordered_map` can hold only one entry with a given key.

Comment: If you want to iterate through the _buckets_ you should not use `gasValuesTable.size()` but `gasValuesTable.bucket_count()`. Otherwise you'll most likely iterate out of bounds.

Comment: *"when I try to iterate though the map, its not getting all the values"* -- your current code is not complete enough to demonstrate this. It's also more complicated than necessary. (See [mre].) Drop `gasValuesTable`, and focus on **one** `unordered_map` with as few elements as necessary to demonstrate that one of the elements is skipped when you iterate over the map. See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) -- focus on your real problem (skipped elements), not the thing (buckets) that you think will help you solve your real problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik *""Collision" means that, for two keys a and b, a != b but hash(a) == hash(b)"* - that's just a subset of collisions, which happen whenever hash(a) % bucket_count() == hash(b) % bucket_count().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to iterate through an `unordered_map` is simply:

```
for (const auto& [key, value] : gasValuesTable)
    cout << key << ", " << value << '\n';
```

Your code was nearly correct to explicitly use an outer loop over buckets, and an inner loop over the elements that hashed to the bucket, but you need to iterate the outer loop from [`0`..`.bucket_count()`), not to `.size()` (which is the number of elements stored in the hash table).  Unless you've been doing more erase operations than inserts, or you've explicitly changed the `max_load_factor`, the `load_factor` will likely be in the 0.5 to 1.0 range, which means you'll miss a lot of elements if you only iterate to `.size() - 1`.

As others have said in comments, `unordered_map` only keeps one value per key.  If you want to have multiple values associated with a single key, you can either use an `unordered_multimap` or have e.g. `unordered_map<key, std::vector<value>>`, and push values into the `vector`.

---

Unless you actively want to force flushing of the output stream, it's often better to use `\n` rather than `endl`.  Flushing can be useful if you think the program might crash before the next output is done, or if some other program or output reader might want to read the output as early as possible.  But, flushing interferes with the normal stream buffering, slowing down your program.